# Export Chrome blob storage?

Tags: google-chrome

What methods are there to export blob storage?

They can be inspected at chrome://blob-internals/ and saved one by one, but I am not seeing a way to do batch export/extract

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS 10.9, I found this huge (13Go) folder:

`/Users/my_name/library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/`...
...`blob_storage/6eb4cfb9-598c-476c-abce-725e170a0ddb`

So I guess you can copy it to export it manually?

*Preliminary apologies: now, since this topic is empty and for sure it won't bother anybody, please allow me to ask my question: I found this folder for a different purpose, to clean up my disk. I located it by its huge size and I was wondering if I can delete it. When I google ask what Chrome Blob Storage is, there is no specific answer, so maybe you could explain me **what it is for? And what could happen if I delete it**?*

Comment: Chrome Blob Storage is how websites can store large files and operate on them locally while the page is open. For example, a website may download a video from the server and keep it in a Blob, then point the `<video>` player to it and the playback would continue even if the device loses internet connection. Or if the file needs to be decrypted before saving on the device (e.g., Mega), the site would create a blob with decrypted contents and initiate a "download" of that blob, instead of encrypted contents from the server.

Comment: If you delete the folder, open websites may lose stored state and the browser could enter an unstable state. But otherwise, it is equivalent to just closing the browser. The browser should cleanup that folder when shutting down.